# Define a default dependency in Gradle and overwrite it for specific buildTypes

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, implementation

I have an Android project with many different buildTypes like debug, alpha, beta, performance, etc. What I would like to achieve is to include a library version by default (for all buildTypes) except for the "debug" one. I tried using the "force = true" but I guess it is for transitive dependency only and not for the current dependency.

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.test:my-lib:1.0"
  debugImplementation("com.test:my-lib:1.0-debug"){
    force = true
  }
}
```

I could define the non-debug dependency manually for each buildTypes, but I would like a more dynamic way for when more buildFlavor will be added. Any idea?

Comment: I have the same issue, have you solve it?

Comment: No, I ended up declaring the library dependency for each build type with ```perfImplementation, alphaImplementation, betaImplementation, etc``` but since the library is updated a lot, I extracted the version number in a global gralde variable.

```
buildscript {
    ext.versions = [
       'my-lib' : '1.0',
    ]
```